# Multiple space delimiter split string

Tags: string, vb.net

I have a string like

```
string = "computer prog  <5spaces>   data mining  <5spaces>   oops concept"
```

As we can see clearly computer prog, data mining etc., are one continuous string and the delimiter is 5 spaces between the strings `"     "`.

I need to split based on this in vb.net - so far I tried regex.split which works but results in giving 2 empty strings additionally and it's tedious to remove those additional strings.

I also tried using the string.split method but again it's taking even single white space also delimiters.

Below are the tried options:
regex.split
string.split

None give me the required result. I am not sure what I need to use. I even tried the option of stringsplitoption.removesapceentry (something like that) to get the desired result inside the split method, but none worked.

```
Dim array_keyskills As String() = res.Split(" ".ToCharArray,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
system.Windows.MessageBox.Show(array_keyskills(2) & array_keyskills.Length & " key skills") 'Display
```

Comment: please wait i will post the response in 2 mins

Comment: Dim array_keyskills As String() = res.Split("     ".ToCharArray,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        system.Windows.MessageBox.Show(array_keyskills(2) & array_keyskills.Length & "        key skills") 'Display

Comment: the output was total number of splited strings is 20 !!! but only 10 words are there , apperently this statement took single space also as delimiter though i gave 5 spaces as delimiter option !!!

Comment: well that is what the code i pasted. , it contains 5 spaces in the split method but stack over flow reduces it to 1. but anyway it did not work . i even said what is the result

Comment: (Oh, and it is HTML which reduces multiple white spaces to one, not Stack Overflow.)

Comment: From the docs for RemoveEmptyEntries "The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty string" A space is Not an empty string.

Comment: yea but anyway , the problem is a single word computer prog is also considered to be two words "computer" "program

Comment: @AndrewMorton For a simple .Split, splitting by a single character both `s.Split(",".ToCharArray)` and `s.Split(","c)` ,using the type character, work.

Comment: @mary here the delimiter is a 5 spaced string. not just single spaces. and the induvidual elements are themselves single space which we should not consider coz they are one words. refer my question for more clarity. i think ur making andrews assumptions clear!!

Answer (score 4):

The following short program:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "computer prog     data mining     oops concept"
        Dim parts = s.Split({"     "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        For Each p In parts
            Console.WriteLine(p)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

outputs:

```
computer prog
data mining
oops concept
```

If your data does not work that way then you should examine it to find which whitespace characters are in it which *appear* to be spaces but are not.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
array_keyskills = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(res,"     ").Where(
                  Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(s)
                  ).ToArray()
```